# Verify google chat bot messages in go

Tags: go, jwt, bots, google-chat

I am trying to create a google chat bot that is receiving some post via google chat and sends the data to a spreadsheet. All of this is working fine but I am struggling with doing the authentication.

I followed the docs provided [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop#verifying_bot_authenticity) and tried to translate functionality to go. Unfortunately I fail miserably. ;-D

What did I do?

I use `"github.com/coreos/go-oidc"` to run the verification.

Setup the verifier like that:

```
const (
    audience            string = "my-project-id"
    publicCertUrlPrefix string = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/"
    chatIssuer          string = "chat@system.gserviceaccount.com"
)

func init() {
    context = cnx.Background()
    keySet := oidc.NewRemoteKeySet(context, publicCertUrlPrefix+chatIssuer)
    config := &oidc.Config{
        SkipClientIDCheck: true,
        ClientID:          audience,
    }
    verifier = oidc.NewVerifier(chatIssuer, keySet, config)
}
```

And try to run verification by doing:

```
func VerifyToken(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // no authorization for health endpoint
        if r.URL.Path == "/health" {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        if authHeader == "" {
            logger.Debug("No authorization header is provided")
            http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        authHeaderParts := strings.Fields(authHeader)
        if len(authHeaderParts) != 2 || strings.ToLower(authHeaderParts[0]) != "bearer" {
            logger.Debug("Authorization header is not valid")
            http.Error(w, "Authorization header format must be Bearer {token}", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        token := authHeaderParts[1]
        if _, e := verifier.Verify(context, token); e != nil {
            logger.Debug("Invalid token: ", e.Error())
            http.Error(w, "Invalid token", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following error:

`Invalid token: failed to verify signature: failed to verify id token signature`

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we got it working by setting the proper URL for the key as we are expecting a `jwt` token, the URL has to be: `https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/`.

```
const (
    audience            string = "my-project-id"
    jwtURL              string = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/"
    chatIssuer          string = "chat@system.gserviceaccount.com"
)

func init() {
    context = cnx.Background()
    keySet := oidc.NewRemoteKeySet(context, jwtURL+chatIssuer)
    config := &oidc.Config{
        SkipClientIDCheck: true,
        ClientID:          audience,
    }
    verifier = oidc.NewVerifier(chatIssuer, keySet, config)
}
```